# How can I get two inputs (max and min) which should be greater or less than each other in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to get two inputs (max and min) from user in which max should not be lower than min and min should not exceed max.
What checks should be applied to achieve this?

Here is my JSX

```
<div className="flex items-center">
                    <p>Min</p>
                    <input name="min" type="number" value={min} min="1" max="5" 
                       onChange= {(e)=>handleMin(e)}/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="flex items-center">
                    <p>Max</p>
                    <input name="max" type="number" value={max} min="1" max="5" 
                       onChange=(e)=>handleMax(e)}/>
                  </div>
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
  const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
  const [max, setMax] = useState(5);

  const handleMin = (e) => {
     if (min < max) {
         setMin(e.target.value);
     }
  };

   const handleMax = (e) => {
      if (max > min) {
          setMax(e.target.value);
      }
   };
```

[image]

When it gets equal (which it should not), inputs stuck and unchangeable. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`s should be checking `e.target.value`, not `min` and `max`:

```
const handleMin = (e) => {
    const value = +e.target.value;  // Convert to number
    if (value < max) {              // Test `value` before setting
        setMin(value);
    }
};

const handleMax = (e) => {
    const value = +e.target.value;  // Convert to number
    if (value > min) {              // Test `value` before setting
        setMax(value);
    }
};
```

Separately, `onChange={(e) => handleMin(e)}` and `onChange={(e) => handleMax(e)}` can more simply be written `onChange={handleMin}` and `onChange={handleMax}`.

Live example with changes:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [min, setMin] = useState(0);
    const [max, setMax] = useState(5);

    const handleMin = (e) => {
        const value = +e.target.value;
        if (value < max) {
            setMin(value);
        }
    };

    const handleMax = (e) => {
        const value = +e.target.value;
        if (value > min) {
            setMax(value);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex items-center">
                <p>Min</p>
                <input
                    name="min"
                    type="number"
                    value={min}
                    min="1"
                    max="5"
                    onChange={handleMin}
                />
            </div>

            <div className="flex items-center">
                <p>Max</p>
                <input
                    name="max"
                    type="number"
                    value={max}
                    min="1"
                    max="5"
                    onChange={handleMax}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```